# Screenshot including camera preview

Tags: ios, swift, camera, screenshot

This code is for taking a screenshot:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
let imageRef = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

When I open the camera preview and take the screenshot, all I get is a white view but no camera shot. Is there a way to also include what is on the camera?
If this doesn't make any sense then what could be the alternative?
Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646632/taking-a-screenshot-when-camera-is-on-ios

Comment: Thank you Dharmesh. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Your welcome..and dont forget to post answer if it works..:)

Comment: Hi @user2828182 do you mind to share your answer?