# How to return image from AV Foundation still capture and add it to graphics context for a screenshot?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, avfoundation

I have a camera preview which works great. I want to take a screenshot of it and everything on top of it. However, since the usual screenshot approach: CALayer's renderInContext does not render content from the camera, I need to add it separately.

I have this function in my view controller captures the image and saves it to the camera roll.

```
 @IBAction func snapStillImage(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("snapStillImage")
        (self.previewView.layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer).connection.enabled=false;


        dispatch_async(self.sessionQueue, {
            // Update the orientation on the still image output video connection before capturing.

            let videoOrientation =  (self.previewView.layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer).connection.videoOrientation

            self.stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).videoOrientation = videoOrientation

            // Flash set to Auto for Still Capture
            ViewController.setFlashMode(AVCaptureFlashMode.Auto, device: self.videoDeviceInput!.device)



            self.stillImageOutput!.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(self.stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo), completionHandler: {
                (imageDataSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, error: NSError!) in

                if error == nil {
                    let data:NSData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer)
                    let image:UIImage = UIImage( data: data)!

                    let libaray:ALAssetsLibrary = ALAssetsLibrary()
                    let orientation: ALAssetOrientation = ALAssetOrientation(rawValue: image.imageOrientation.rawValue)!
                    libaray.writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum(image.CGImage, orientation: orientation, completionBlock: nil)

                    print("save to album")


                }else{
//                    print("Did not capture still image")
                    print(error)
                }


            })


        })
    }
```

I want to return the image defined with `let image:UIImage = UIImage( data: data)!`
so that it is accessible by the following function

```
@IBAction func downloadButton(sender: UIButton) {
    //Create the UIImage



    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(previewView.frame.size, false, 0.0)

    previewView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

    //ALSO ADD image captured with captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection right here to the context.
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()



    //Save it to the camera roll

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

This would let my screenshot include the recently captured image as well as all the stuff on top that gets added with UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

I have heard that you do this by including the image in the completion handler block already included in the captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection function but I am not quite sure how to do this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add the captured still image as a UIImage as a subview of the previewView. Then make the call to renderInContext.

Assuming this code is all going on in the same class, you can make image a property like

```
class CameraViewController: UIViewController {
    var image: UIImage!
    ...
```

Then in `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection`

instead of

```
let image:UIImage = UIImage( data: data)!
```

use

```
self.image = UIImage( data: data)!
```

Then in `downloadButton` use

```
var imageView = UIImageView(frame: previewView.frame)
imageView.image = self.image
previewView.addSubview(imageView)
previewView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
```

You can then remove the imageView if you want

```
imageView.removeFromSuperview()
```

Comment: when I do this, it works great. However, when I rotate my phone, it rotates the imageView into a weird place - with half of it cropped off if I have a portrait picture that is trying to fit inside of a landscape previewView Is there a way to add this subview so that the entire thing fits inside of previewView?

Comment: You could add the image view on the storyboard and use constraints to make it match the previewView dimensions. Or you can add the constraints manually.

Comment: Another way to keep the imageView inside the previewView is to use `override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
        
        coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({ context in }) {  context in
            self.imageView.frame = self.previewView.bounds
        }
    }`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot render content from the camera because CALayer's renderInContext doesn't work.

Nonetheless you want to work that, the following link can help you.

[Taking a screenshot when camera is on -iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646632/taking-a-screenshot-when-camera-is-on-ios)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1702/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010192

Comment: I don't know objective-C very well. Is there a way to convert that code into swift?

Comment: also, I don't think that does what I am asking anyways. It seems to take buffer data using core video if you are in the process of recording a video. I have a camera preview and am simply capturing a photo using .captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection as a UIImage. I want to add this static image to my graphics context.

Comment: Doesn't @RussellAustin's answer suggest `renderInContext` will work for CALayer? Mind elaborating please? Thanks!